# Expansions onto "bases"...?

Tags: fourier-series, taylor-expansion, spherical-harmonics

When we consider expanding functions into fourier series, or taylor series, or onto the spherical harmonics-are these projections onto a basis? Are these bases complete? How can we show this? I know that in physics they talk about fourier as expanding onto vibrational modes, and the spherical harmonics as expansions onto vibrations on a sphere, but I don't understand how we know that we're guaranteed that these expansions will be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...there's the problem that the bases aren't exactly bases in the sense you know and love from your first linear algebra course. For instance, if you expand a square wave as a fourier series, and then sum the series, you'll get back a function that's equal to your square wave...except perhaps at the break-points. A a break point, the FS will sum to the mid-value at the break, while your function might have taken on the upper or lower value. So not every periodic function is equal to the sum of a Fourier series, no. But once you say "equal to the sum of a Fourier Series almost everywhere", then you're OK (as long as you restrict to functions that are square-summable).

How do you know this? I know it's not very satisfying as an answer, but ... well, you read the proofs of the theorems. Dym and McKean's Fourier Series and Integrals gives a great many of these proofs in very little space, but unfortunately they also are a bit short on motivation/explanation for my taste. But if you want the proofs, they're all there, in a compact little volume.

Comment: So it would seem that neither Taylor series, nor fourier series form a complete basis for the space of functions. Do they form a basis for *anything*?

Comment: Oh the fourier basis is for square integrable functions. Taylor series then?

Comment: I don't think that Taylor series look like projections onto a basis, no. Fourier series really *do* -- the integrals of the form $\int f(x) \bar{g(x)} ~dx$ that you compute for various sine-like functions $g$ are exactly inner products, and the sine-like functions form an orthonormal set under this inner product.  For Taylor series...I don't think that there's any such projection argument. If there were, you'd expect a convergence argument as well, but there are functions whose taylor series converge everywhere, but $f$ and its Taylor series agree only at $0$. (ick!)

Comment: So Taylor series are just approximations-what are the requirements for Taylor series to work? Like isn't there an example of an exponential where it doesn't work? Also, for the spherical harmonics-what functions are they a basis for? Solutions to Laplace's Equation?

Comment: I suggest that you read the "Sequences and Series" section of Spivak's *Calculus* to understand "when Taylor series work." I can't explain it in 500 characters. Spherical harmonics are the analogue, on the sphere, to Fourier series on the circle: they're like a basis for the space of $L^2$ functions on the sphere, where the spherical harmonic representation of $f$  equals $f$ except on a set of measure zero.

Comment: I'll read that-Isn't a square wave square integrable? Why don't we recover the wave after doing an inverse transform, then?

Comment: We *do* recover it...but only up to "$L^2$-equality, i.e., equality except on a set of measure zero. That's what I meant about "not quite like the bases you learn about in your first linear algebra course."

Comment: So why is it said to be a basis for square integrable functions, if square integrable functions end up getting warped?

Comment: those are (uncountably) infinite basis; still not all functions may be represented even as an infinite sum of them

Comment: It's not said to be a basis for square-integrable functions. It's more like "a basis for equivalence classes of square integrable functions under the equivalence relation 'equal except on a set of measure zero'." Why study such a thing? Because the analogy with standard basis-ideas is strong, and because (my bias here) such classes represent what's measurable in the real world: just about every measurement process involves observing a function on a small interval and computing some integral of this against a weighting function...and that process masks measure-zero differences.